# AS68RC transmission problems

Tags: transmission, dodge, ram

My name is Matthew Bossard,  I am a Field Service Repair Technician for a small construction company located in Castle Rock Colorado.

The specifics for the vehicle and transmission I am working on are as follows:
2011 Dodge 5500 4wd eguipped with a PTO
VIN: 3D6WU7EL3BG624457
MILES: 182,000
MODS: TIER 4 DELETE ( done by the previous mechanics) 5 inch turbo back exhaust, upgraded Turbo, ECM or other electronic modifications unknown.
TRANS. MODEL: AS68RC
TRANS. SERIAL #: 1E-0839

Symptoms:
1. Slow to engage from a stop 
2. Erratic shifts in 1-2 and 2-3 usually after a stop from cruising at highway speeds. 
3. Fluctuating transmission oil level. (See below)
4. Leaking oil 
5. Random trouble codes pertaining to pressure sensors and shift solenoids

Diagnosis and repair FIRST ATTEMPT 
1. Addressed the leak by changing the pump seal ( the seal that goes around the input shaft from the torque converter into the transmission)
2. While the transmission was out I checked the run out of the torque converter and discovered it to be out of specifications.
3. Upon removal of the torque converter discovered that a bolt for the torque converter had been left Loose by the dealership here in Denver.
4. Replaced the torque converter.
5. Fill torque converter and transmission with Mopar ASRC transmission fluid.
6.cleared codes and  performed q renlearn operation.

Diagnosis and repair SECOND ATTEMPT 
1. The oil is only leaking when the PTO is running or during travel it does not leak in park. 
2. Dropped oil pan inspected filters and magnets found very very little amount of debris. Nothing you wouldn't expect to find from an undamaged transmission.
3. Very little oil came out of the oil pan  with the drain plug removed. I then remove the drain pan and started to loosen the valve body where almost 5 quarts of oil drained out. Now I'm used to oil coming out of the valve body when removed but not more than double the volume that comes out of the oil pan of the transmission.

All of the above statement Sinclair ditions and observations lead me to believe that there is a problem with the oil returning to the drain pan inthe hydraulic flow chart. It is building up pressure and relieving itself through the front of the oil pump.

I'm trying to come to a conclusion of whether the repair is most likely  a solenoid, or a sensor whitch is not working affecting a solenoid that can be replaced, or if it is most likely going to require transmission rebuild?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!